# Redirecting to new tab or window from current page

Tags: html

I am working on localhost:

I have kept

```
`<a href="www.facebook.com" target="_tab">
<div> </div>
</a>`
```

On button click it should redirect and open in new tab. But it shows following url in next tab

```
http://dev01.dev/Umesh/www.facebook.com

ie. localhost/current<dir>/url
```

rather

```
url
```

Comment: target should be target="_blank"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your target is wrong, it should be

```
target="_blank"
```

Answer (score 1):

change `www.facebook.com` to `http://facebook.com`. Also there is no such thing as `_tab` what you want is `_blank`.